# How do I refer to <%# Eval('column')%> in a .aspx scripting tag?

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke, repeater, sqldatasource

Please note that I am using a `SQLDATASOURCE` to perform a `SELECT * FROM myTable`. Here is a small piece of the item template of my repeater:

```
<li>Work Extension: <%# Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT")%></li>
```

Now, lets say that `<%# Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT")%>` is an empty string. How do I go about referencing `<%# Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT")%>` in a `<script language="c#" runat="server">` tag. I know i can do it from the codebehind, by placing the value of the `EVAL` tag in an `asp:label` text property then finding it. Im just looking for a shorter way to say:

```
if(<%# Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT")%> == ""){
<%# Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT")%> == "N/A";
}
```

So I do not have to rebuild my simple DNN Module. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check inline

```
   <%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString()) ? "N/A" : Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT"))%>
```

EDIT:

For complex conditions, I'd prefer to write a public (or protected) method in the codebehind & handle them there

In UI..    `'<%# MyDataItem(Eval("item")) %>'`

```
public string MyDataItem(object value)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString()))
  {
     return "N/A";
  }

  return myValue.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you simply used jQuery to find that item (or items) in the repeater and replace the text inside them with "N/A" instead of trying to do it with C#?

Wrap your eval code in a div, with a class on it, then target anything with that class

```
<div class="workPhone"><%# Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT")%></div>
```

then in jquery something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if($(".workPhone").HTML() == "")
{
    $(".workPhone").HTML("N/A");
}
</script>
```